# Reflection with two assemblies

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

I am tring to get this test to work.

I think the issue is due to the fact that ICosmosJob and ICosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder live in two different assemblies, because if I put both interfaces in the same assembly, it works fine.

For what ever reason, I cannot get IsAssignableFrom(t) to be true for ICosmosJob.

Ideas?

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    ServiceSettingsInfo.ApiConnectionString = "https://testcosmoscoreapi.bergerwebservices.com/";
    ServiceSettingsInfo.ServiceId = 1138;

    string assemblyPath = @"C:\Websites\CosmosJobProcessor\CosmosJobAssemblies\CosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder";

    ICosmosJob implementation = null;

    bool isimplemented = false;
    foreach (string assemblyFile in Directory.GetFiles(assemblyPath, "CosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder.dll"))
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
        var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => typeof(ICosmosJob).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract);
        // this works var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => typeof(ICosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract);

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            if (type.Name == "CosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder")
            {
                implementation = (ICosmosJob)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                implementation.ExecuteAsync(new CosmosJobEntityDto(), "", CancellationToken.None).Wait();
                isimplemented = true;
                break;
            }
        }


    }

    Assert.That(isimplemented, Is.True);
}

public interface ICosmosJob
{
    Task<CosmosJobResponse> ExecuteAsync(CosmosJobEntityDto cosmosJobEntityDto, string url, CancellationToken stoppingToken);
}

public interface ICosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder:  ICosmosJob
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: The code is mentioning both an interface ICosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder and a class CosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder. Are you sure there is no confusion?

Comment: What error/exception did you get?

Comment: In otherwords, for some reason `typeof(ICosmosJob) != [Assembly].GetType("ICosmosJob")`? Does "CosmosApi_Shipment_Workorder.dll" reference the assembly where `ICosmosJob` is defined? Does your test project also reference this same assembly?